# where are windows API functions defined?

Tags: winapi

when you need to use a function you include a header file but wheres the function code is defined?

Comment: is it attached to the OS itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dave, the code lives in the various and many DLL files in your Windows\system32 directory.

Comment: I second this. Almost all of the Windows API calls are part of a DLL. When you link your code you usually load a library which is responsible for loading the appropriate library. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries

Answer (score 4):

The actual code that implements the Win-32 API are defined in various DLLs on your system.  These DLLs have names like kernel32.dll, comctl32.dll etc.  You will find them in C:\Windows\System32.

What generally happens is that you link your code with kernel32.lib etc. that have a little code to dynamically load the DLLs when your program starts.  This allows Win32 API functions to directly call into the DLLS.

Answer (score 1):

Well as explained above you are in the hands of microsoft.
You can always look at the msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com.
For most API functions you can find some information at the bottom.
For most function you get from there:

Minimum supported client
Minimum supported server
Header
Library
DLL
Unicode and ANSI names